# Sharing functions between +page.svelte in SvelteKit

Tags: sveltekit

I'm my `+page.svelte` I need to refresh the displayed data when a new websocket event arrives for the selected device (in the option list). This is my +page.svelte for one of my device_type:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { base } from "$app/paths"
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import type { PageData } from './$types'
  import { invalidate, invalidateAll } from '$app/navigation';
  import { AreaChart } from '@carbon/charts-svelte'
  import '@carbon/styles/css/styles.css'
  import '@carbon/charts-svelte/styles.css'
  import options from '$lib/options'
  import { page } from '$app/stores';
  import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

  export let data: PageData
  $: ({ devices, device_type, device_selected } = data)
  $: device_data = []

  // Set up a writable store for WebSocket connection
  const websocket = writable(null);
  function handleWebSocketMessage(event) {
    const edata = JSON.parse(event.data);
    let device_type = ""
    if (edata.device.includes('WeatherStation_n')) {
      device_type = "weatherstation_n"
      console.log('WeatherStation_n')
    } else if (edata.device.includes('WeatherStation_v')) {
      device_type = "weatherstation_v"
      console.log('WeatherStation_v')
    } else {
      console.log('Unknown device')
    }
    //refresh_data(device_type, edata.device)
    fetch_data();
  }

  const refresh_data = async (device_type: String, device_selected: String) => {
      console.log(`refresh_data ${base}/api/${device_type}/${device_selected}`)
      const url = `${base}/api/${device_type}/${device_selected}`;
      //invalidate(url);
      //invalidate(`${base}/${device_type}/`);
      //invalidate();
  }


  export const fetch_data = async () => {
    data.device_selected = device_selected //set and update doesn't work why?
    extOptions = { ...options,  title: `${device_selected}` }
    const url = `${base}/api/${device_type}/${device_selected}`;
    console.log(`fetch_data ${url}`)
    const response = await fetch(url)
    device_data = await response.json();
    return device_data
  }

  let extOptions = { ...options }
  onMount(() => {
    // Establish WebSocket connection when component mounts
    const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8765');
    ws.addEventListener('message', handleWebSocketMessage);
    // Update the store with WebSocket connection
    websocket.set(ws);    
    fetch_data() 
  });
</script>

<h2>Devices</h2>
<select bind:value={device_selected} on:change={() => (fetch_data())} >
  {#each devices as device, index}
      <option value={device}>
        {device}
      </option>
  {/each}
</select>

<AreaChart data={device_data} options={extOptions} style="padding:2rem;" />
```

As you can see the AreaChart get the `device_data` updated once a websocket event for the `device_selected` arrives.
By using the fetch_data() works but not using `invalidate()` in `refresh_data()`

Anyway my question is: how to share the websocket related code between all my +page.svelte? I can't put it in +layout.svelte because I can't trigger fetch_data() in +page.svelte and I still don't know in advance which device will be selected in the option list.
I'm confused on the best strategy to adopt in general for common function that I want shared on all the pages and when is feasible to move them in `+layout.svelte` given for example that I can't call `invalidate` in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If stuff is used on multiple pages, it should be in `+layout.svelte`.

You can communicate between layout and page via a [context](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#setcontext). You can set an object that contains functions, like the one used to refresh the data, and [stores](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store), so data can be updated on the page reactively. If you only need one data source you can also just make the entire context object a store and extend it with additional functions.

```js
// in layout
const socketStore = writable(null);
setContext('socket-context', {
   subscribe: socketStore.subscribe,
   refresh() { ... },
});
```

```js
// in page
const socketContext = getContext('socket-context');

$: console.log('Socket data changed:', $socketContext)

function onSomeEvent() {
  socketContext.refresh();
}
```

---

Using the given dependencies, you can just add the local data as arguments:

```js
// in layout
const device_data = writable([]);
setContext('device-data-context', {
   subscribe: device_data.subscribe,
   async fetch(device_type, device_selected) {
     // [fetch here]

     device_data.set(fetchedData);
   },
});
```

```html
<!-- in page -->
<script>
  ...
  export let data: PageData
  $: ({ devices, device_type, device_selected } = data)
  const device_data = getContext('device-data-context');
  ...
</script>
<select bind:value={device_selected}
        on:change={() =>
          device_data.fetch(device_type, device_selected)
        }>
  ...
</select>

<AreaChart data={$device_data} ... />
```

(This code has a race condition by the way. Quick changes of the selected item can lead to data being shown that does not belong to the current selection if requests finish out of original order.)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't fully understand how to apply it to my case: I now have 'socket-context' object that is shared among all the pages, but the device selection happens on the +page. Should I update $device_data on the page or in the layout?

Comment: Does not particularly matter, you could provide a function that takes the new device as argument or expose a store to be set. In the latter case you need a store so the layout can react to the change, a regular property on the context would no suffice.

Comment: As you can see I've already `devices, device_type, device_selected` in the `$page` store. Should I put it in the context object instead? or make a reference? Do you have a full example I can look at? I'm a bit confused the first time

Comment: You can directly use the `$page` store in the layout, if you want to. Of course its type will be uncertain if not all pages that use the layout provide the same data. If the data can be loaded independent of the page, you can also just load it in a [layout `load` function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#layout-data). It all depends on how exactly your pages relate to the layout. If all pages have the same data, you might be able to get away with not using a context at all if everything can be encapsulated in the layout and you just need to react to `$page.data` changes.

Comment: so far `devices` get populated on the load() for the `device_type` in the +page.server.ts. `device_selected` is set in the input select box. they are  all in the $page.data but +layout can't read them before. They are needed to update the data in fetch_data() `const url = `${base}/api/${device_type}/${device_selected}`;` and to select the relevant device when a websocket message arrives. But if I have this logic in +layout I can't access the updated variables isnt' it?

Comment: That is what the context would be for, you can update a store in the context and the page can react to its changes/use its value directly in markup using `$`-notation. Also, if you use a layout `load` function to load everything, you could just execute [`invalidateAll`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-invalidateall) to make it re-evaluate, which then automatically gets passed to the page `data` as well, which again would probably make the context obsolete.

Comment: I'm not loading everything in load() as I've wrote, because this depends on the device selection... Since +layout is executed first, the change in the store that later happens in +page is not reflected back. Show me an example of how can I put fetch_data() in the +layout.svelte using the context, I'm not able to make it work...

Comment: It's really not that complicated. You just add any local value dependencies as arguments to the function exposed on the context and in the function you set the store using the fetched data. I added a more explicit example; if you still have issues, you have to be more specific than "I'm not able to make it work.".

Comment: The solution was to use the context + a writable store and don't rely on the $page store. I've made a simpler example to test the use of the stores at https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-xpchia?file=src%2Froutes%2F%2Bpage.svelte